# How to return the unique ID after DB insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

Using ASP.Net C# with MVC3

Here is my insert code.

```
var fInfo = new FileInfo {filename = filefield.FileName, dateadded = DateTime.Now.ToString()};
db.FileInfoes.AddObject(fInfo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

How would i retrieve the newly created ubique id to display a link for the user to see what they just uploaded and bookmark it ect,,,

Comment: the fInfo Id's field will be populated after the call to db.SaveChanges

Comment: What DB access technology do you use? EF, LINQ2SQL? Is the ID generated by the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After saving the changes, you can access the ID using your fInfo object.

Answer (score 2):

Is your ID defined as an `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server??

If you're using Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework, those columns are **automatically** updated in your object after saving - no extra work required.

[image]

*Linq-to-SQL sample*

[image]

*Entity Framework sample*

Comment: Marc what program did you use for the nice circling? I like it quite a bit!

Comment: @AdamTuliper: pasted the screenshots into [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) - which is **FREE** btw! - and then used their "rounded rectangle" drawing tool